# Spyder 5 No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied

Tags: spyder

I get the following error after having upgraded to `Spyder 5`

```
  No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect.
```

The interface also looks 'not nice' (I am guessing without the stylesheet).

[image: Display 5.0 - 1]

Downgrading to Spyder 4 causes everything to appear in a single column (Code area, console, variable explorer etc, all one below other with ugly overlap to make it unusable).

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restore your Spyder 4 layout using View --> Window Layout --> Spyder default layout.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to restore the older layout by looking in the `~/. config/spyder-py3/config` and restoring older versions of ini files.  I see now that there was an easier way. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's a warning and it doesn't affect loading our new stylesheet. Please simply ignore it.

*Note*: It's unfortunate that you don't like our style because it's the one Spyder will use from now on.

Comment: Thanks for providing spyder. It's a great IDE!! I just installed 5.0.0 in Ubuntu, but maybe what @Hrishikesh meant with "not nice" is e.g. that all dropdown menu icons overlap with the menu texts, and tab  navigator arrows are on top of the right-most tab. I don't think that is "your style" now ;-) .. I installed miniconda freshly (python 3.9.2).

Comment: The problem with icons overlapping text will be fixed in our 5.0.1 version. The other one (navigator arrows) will be fixed in 5.0.2, to be released in three weeks.

Comment: Spyder is great, l've been using it since Spyder 2 for my python code. I meant what @Dr. V said,  the icons and interface looks like it's built with primitive Qt5 without any stylesheet, and there's no padding between text and icons in the drop-down menus etc. (I couldn't get the screenshot of those as when the drop-down menus are active, screenshot key wasn't working). But I've restored Spyder 4 now and will update after the next version is out. Thank you.

Comment: Those problems are fixed now in our 5.0.1 version.

Comment: It seems to me that Spyder (5.0.2) looks different under python 3.8 than under 3.9. And I think it looks good under 3.9 but not under 3.8.
Specifically in the dark mode, under 3.8 the tabs are light. And the source file path, directly above the tabs, is black text on dark gray background. Almost invisible.

Comment: Another question about that warning:
You say it can be ignored, but can it also be eliminated somehow? It gives me an uncomfortable feeling as if I've installed something wrong or so. Does installing a certain package (or version of it) make the warning go away?

Comment: @Reinier, the differences in appearance are due to the PyQt version you're using, not to Python. About the warning, no, it can't be eliminated by users. We'll avoid displaying it in our next version.