# Spyder 5 Disable Warning: "No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied"

Tags: spyder

I get the following warning when I run Spyder 5:
`No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied`
In an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979095/spyder-5-no-qcoreapplication-instance-found-application-patches-not-applied), a spyder maintainer replied saying this warning can just be ignored.
Is there a way to disable it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, there's no way to disable it.