# Spyder not launching - No QCoreApplication instance found

Tags: spyder, anaconda3

I get the following when I try to run Spyder from a Python 3.7 32 bit environment:
[image]

I don't really know how resolve this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I read the below fix but I am not getting any Windows like in the below to try it.

[Spyder 5 No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979095/spyder-5-no-qcoreapplication-instance-found-application-patches-not-applied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the error is related with DLLs required for the ssl module:

```
import _ssl                 # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

To fix that you will need to either make available for your python installation the missing DLL (probably `libssl.dll` and `libcrypto.dll`) or maybe try to use a python version bellow 3.7.

Also, the message `Spyder 5 No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied...` is just a warning as described in one of the responses here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979214/15954282